# How to preserve fonts installed by Advanced Installer package even after uninstallation?

Tags: windows-installer, installation, packaging

One simple question, I've used [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/index.html) along time ago to pack my files and deploy them on the client machine, and I used to pack some special fonts used by my application.
The problem is: when I uninstall the package created with **Advanced Insatller** the fonts included in the package also gets removed from the operation system, How can I preserve fonts after package uninstallation from within *Advanced installer IDE* ?
**PS**: I can do it using **[Inno Installer](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)** by using something like:

```
uninsneveruninstall
```

Example:

```
[Files]
;;Fonts:
Source: "C:\Windows\Fonts\DS-DIGI.TTF"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall; FontInstall: "DS-Digital"
```

I want something like that in Advanced Installer.
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it eventually!

1. First go to the file or font you want to keep after uninstall.
2. Right click and choose ***Go to component***.

   [image]
3. The component that hold the file(s) will be highlighted and you can expand it to see the inner files:

[image]

4. Just make sure that the files are selected within the component and choose **Permenant** from the **Component properties** section.

Answer (score 0):

They have an option to preserve files. Just try to check the [Do not overwrite existing file](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/file-operations-tab.html) option with condition set to 1 (always).

Another solution will be to edit the "UnregisterFonts" action condition not to execute on uninstall. Search for the "InstallExecuteSequence" table in the "Table Editor" view and edit the condition of the "UnregisterFonts" action to `Installed AND (REMOVE <> "ALL")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for reply, but unfortunately it didn't help.